# react-intl stopped working "Missing locale data for locale"

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-intl

I have code for last 2 months and everything worked fine until few days back, I removed all my modules and did npm install again. Now react-intl started throwing an error when I change language in my dropdown. In my App.js I have something like this:

```
let { params, locale, route } = this.props;

const lc = locale || params.lc || 'en';
const translation = translations[lc] || translations.en

<IntlProvider locale={lc} messages={translation.messages}>
     {this.props.children}
</IntlProvider>
```

And In my language component, on dropdown change I'm changing locale. When I console log lc, and messages before  I get correct lc returned and array with translated messages, then error is thrown, as you can see on img: [image]

The version I used in project is "2.0.0-beta-2" but it looks like it was updated without changing version number.

Anyone have an idea what happened? Thanks

Comment: are you able to fix the issue? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @AliRaza hey yes, I had to do addLocaleData(english); and that language you are pulling from react-intl/locale-data/en, also addLocaleData is function from react-intl lib

Comment: thank you Markuz. It worked for me.

Comment: would be great if you could edit and add it as an answer!

Comment: would love to see your translations object + the solution